# References for studying and understanding different groups of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Specially in case of the groups of different matrices, I become very much uncomfortable. So a suggestion for any good book comprising discussions on various types of groups of matrices will be very much helpful....

Comment: What do you mean by "different groups of matrices"? Do you mean like the general linear group, the orthogonal group, the special orthogonal group and the unitary group?

Comment: @Arthur yes groups like them.

Comment: Search for books on " Lie Groups " .

Comment: @DonAntonio I don't want to indulge in typical Lie Algebra, I modify my question by stating - I want a book that will be very much descriptive and will tell ample about the different useful properties about the matrices, not getting into lie algebra.

Comment: I would recommend [Brian C. Hall's text](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783319134666), which deals mostly with matrices and doesn't say much about the more abstract manifold/tangent space definitions.